# What spelling dictionaries does Ubuntu use?

Tags: spell-checking

Do all applications use the same dictionary for spell checking? If not, which applications use which dictionaries in a typical desktop installation, or where can I find out?

Answer (score 2):

Some apps are using a common dictionary (such as *Evolution*, which use `aspell-*` packages). Some apps are using their own dictionary, such as *Libreoffice*, which uses `libreoffice-l10n-[language code]` and `language-support-writing-[language code]` packages.

Comment: Where can I find out about applications besides those you've used as examples?